# How to animate a Div on Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to figure out how to rotate a `div` based off of my scrolling. I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/SSelke/pen/mQZqYN) that demonstrates the behaviour that I would like to achieve.

However, I do not know hot to make it work with scrolling. Essentially, I would like to scroll down and have the word **Data** move in a counter-clockwise rotation. And if I decide to scroll up and down it should move with the speed of the scroll. I only want it to move 90deg up or down.
Thanks!

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.button');
var btnUp = document.querySelector('.button-up')

btnUp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(".parent").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-90deg)";
  document.querySelector(".child").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(90deg)";
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector(".parent").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
  document.querySelector(".child").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(0deg)";
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  margin: 100px auto 30px auto;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-0deg);
  transition: transform 0.7s linear;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 278px;
  /* -child size/2 */
  left: 130px;
  /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Data
  </div>
</div>

<button class="button">Click Down</button>
<button class="button-up">Click Up</button>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/SSelke/pen/mQZqYN

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

and in script

```
<script>
  AOS.init();
</script>
```

then in div

```
<div data-aos="fade-down"></div> //you can use whatever you want's
```

for further information

> [this website](https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/) helps you on how to make it work

and

You can find out more at [AOS Animation](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer